# Programatically launch phone internal setting dialog on Android phone

Tags: android, android-scripting, dual-sim

I have an philips w626 dual-sim android 2.3.5 phone.

When I manually turn on data connection, SIM selection dialog appears and I have to choose what Card should data be switched on.
And exaclty this Dialog I want launch programatically, for example using some Tasker plugin when I start an application which needs data connection.

Phone is rooted, I can use adb shell, logcat,

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Snippet

```
    int adb = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
  Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 0);
 // toggle the USB debugging setting
 adb = adb == 0 ? 1 : 0;
 Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, adb);
```

add these permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

for further Help have a look  at the following [Link](http://code.google.com/p/secure-settings-widget/source/browse/src/com/lieryan/adbwidget/ADBAppWidgetProvider.java?r=eb23b2d6989ccade05f095806db5888f1ba62737)

Comment: Sorry, probably I was not clear enough. To make it more clear, the question is: A) What do I have to do to launch phone internal settings dialog (in my case SIM Card selection for data transfer on dual-sim phone) and B) when I know what to launch, how to do it